# Add label to ordered list numbers for homework questions

Tags: lists

I want to make an ordered list that not only displays an Arabic number at the beginning of each new list element, but also contains the prefix "**Question #**" (*i.e.* **Question #1**, **Question #2**, etc.) in bold. How to achieve this? Additionally, how to skip some given numbers, for example, pass from **Question #3** to **Question #5** while skipping **Question #4**?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example demonstrating your solution attempt. Generally, the best way to format lists in LaTeX is via the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @User23456234 Fogiel's answer is just what I need. Should I edit the question accordingly to your comment anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, it provides key-val syntax to customize lists easily.

To skip a number in an enumerate list, you should use `\refstepcounter` in the middle of the list.

Here is a possible way to get what you want

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Questoin \arabic*},align=left, leftmargin=*]
        \item body of question 1
        \item body of question 2
        \item body of question 3\refstepcounter{enumi}
        \item body of question 5
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great, clear and complete answer! I have a question: When I use your code in my document, the "Question" part of each element is ignored by the margins. In other words, the "Question" part sticks out from the margins, and only the numbers are within the margins. How do I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: @GPWR, I've edited the list options to fix that. For more information regarding this, read page 6 of `enumitem` documentation

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very helpful! God bless.